# Classifier produces continuous values rather than distinct labels

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification, pattern-recognition, mlp

[This documentation article](https://in.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/gs/classify-patterns-with-a-neural-network.html) explains how to apply a multi layer perceptron for a classification task. I have an input feature vector of length 80 and would like to train a multi layer perceptron to classify the input vectors into two categories -- 0 and 1. My output layer contains 1 node.

**Problem 1)** I expect the classifier to have a binary output, but the model outputs real-valued numbers (between `0` and `1`). Why does this happen and how to transform it to binary classes? It is not mentioned in the tutorial link how to obtain the binary valued labels, i.e. what function to use in the last layer.

To clarify, once the model output is calculated (below are the first 4 output values),

```
y = 
    0.1042
    0.9961
    0.9956
    0.0049
```

I can use a simple threshold function like `bin_target = y>=0.5` where all numbers greater than or equal to 0.5 are labelled as one and the rest as zero. However, the manual choice of a threshold appears arbitrary to me.

**Problem 2)** Calculation of MSE: Should the mean squared error or simple the error to report the performance be calculated between the known binary valued targets `Y` and the real-valued model's output `y` or `perfClassify = y_bin - Y`?

---

The code below is my attempt to classify the data `inputs`.

```
% Create a Pattern Recognition Network
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = init(net);
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,Y);  % Y=targets

% Test the Network
y = net(inputs);

bin_target = y>=0.5;
error1 = bin_target-Y'; 
% OR
error2 = y - Y';
```

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question to explain 3 things more clearly: **what is the intended outcome**, **what is happening at the moment**, and **how you tried to fix it**. Please focus on making your question **self-contained**, that is - having all required information in the body of the post, so that it is answerable without having to follow a link. The link is good for context, but perhaps linking to specific figures in that page would be more helpful in explaining your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Problem 1** happens because the default output transfer function is `'softmax'`, which is a continuous function (technically, a probability distribution). Such output includes "confidence" information and not just the output class. My *opinion* is that `0.5` is the correct threshold for a binary classification problem, because to my understanding the value that gets output means "probability that this inputs corresponds to class `true`".

```matlab
>> net = patternnet;
>> disp(net.layers{net.numLayers}.transferFcn);
softmax
```

Unfortunately, I cannot comment whether `softmax` is suitable for your problem, but if you want to change it, you can find a list of options using `help nntransfer`:

```
>> help nntransfer
  Neural Network Transfer Functions.

    compet - Competitive transfer function.
    elliotsig - Elliot sigmoid transfer function.
    hardlim - Positive hard limit transfer function.
    hardlims - Symmetric hard limit transfer function.
    logsig - Logarithmic sigmoid transfer function.
    netinv - Inverse transfer function.
    poslin - Positive linear transfer function.
    purelin - Linear transfer function.
    radbas - Radial basis transfer function.
    radbasn - Radial basis normalized transfer function.
    satlin - Positive saturating linear transfer function.
    satlins - Symmetric saturating linear transfer function.
    softmax - Soft max transfer function.
    tansig - Symmetric sigmoid transfer function.
    tribas - Triangular basis transfer function.

  Main nnet function list.
```

Perhaps what you're looking for is [`hardlim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/hardlim.html). To change the transfer function simply assign a valid value to the `transferFcn` field of the last layer (e.g. `net.layers{net.numLayers}.transferFcn = 'hardlim';`).

As for **Problem 2**, as explained in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46413/mean-square-error-of-classification), it is beneficial to use the **continuous scores**.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, the method to change the transfer function of the last layer, should I mention the number of the layer in the statement `net.layers{net.numLayers}.transferFcn = 'hardlim'`? So, if there is one input layer, followed by two hidden layers and then an output layer, what should this command be?

Comment: No need to change the command, it always refers to the last layer. Of course, don't take my word for it - you should run it and verify the result on your own.

Comment: thank you very much. REgarding the MSE answer, I do have a concern about the procedure of comparing the real-valued model's output with the target class labels. This is because the MSE may not be close to zero in this case. Moreover, using the real-valued output may be contradictory if the confusion matrix is also used as a performance tool -- the confusion matrix would show 100% accuracy whereas the MSE is quite high. However, if the MSE is compared between the labels (i.e., after converting the real-valued model's output using 0.5 as the threshold) then it may be zero. What do you suggest?

Comment: It will be helpful if you can update your answer by elaborating a bit more on  this point -- if MSE and confusion matrix are both used then both the methods are using different values. MSE is using the error between real-valued outputs and binary valued targets. On the other hand, confusion matrix is using binary value.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not an expert on this topic, so I cannot elaborate without reading the article in the linked post. In any case, this sounds like a completely different problem worthy of separate discussion. I suggest you either open a new question on [stats.se], comment on the linked question asking for this clarification, or send the author of the post an email about their article. If you feel this answer is not useful without that information, I'll delete it.